# Add release notes for each version in jfrog artfactory

Tags: android, android-studio, artifactory

I have uploaded a new version in jfrog artifactory from android studio. How can I add release notes for each version in jfrog artfactory.

Answer (score 2):

There is no out of the box "Release Notes" section in Artifactory. You can, however, use the properties feature for adding your release note as a property.

https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Properties

If you need to have release notes as a real release notes to end users, I would recommend looking into Bintray for your release.

http://www.bintray.com

Disclaimer: I work at JFrog which is the company that owns both Artifactory and Bintray